# Spring Integration Header Update Not Reflected between PublishSubscribe SubFlows

Tags: spring-integration

May be it is my lack of knowledge, I'm seeing the behavior where a header value updated in `SubFlow1` of `PublishSubscribe` is NOT reflecting in the other `SubFlow2` which is executed on the same main thread.

```
.publishSubscribeChannel(pubSubSpec -> pubSubSpec.subscribe(flow1())
                                                .subscribe(flow2()))
.get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Message` is immutable by definition. So, in those to sub-flows you really deal with different messages.

Imaging you have to `Map` objects which contain the same key. Modifying one of them definitely does not effect the other instance.

If you still think that you need share the same object between sub-flows, then consider to have a mutable object as a header. For example an `AtomicReference` will do the trick to be shared as a header value between different message instance. Then modifying this value in a header will lead you to the reflected change from one sub-flow to another.

In general it is better to think only in immutable object since there is no guarantee how your messages are going to travel through distributed asynchronous solution.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, helps and has helped a lot in our (fascinating) Spring Integration journey.

Comment: While using `AtomicReference` as one of the header type, is the following a normal way to convert to String  type and then map to WebFlux / Http request headers via `mappedRequestHeaders` or is there a more elegant approach using Converters? `hdrEnricherSpec.headerExpression(HTTP_HDR_ABC, "headers['" + HTTP_HDR_ABC + "'].toString()", true)`

Comment: No, since this is a non-standard type for HTTP headers, there is no other way than convert it manually. You may just use a function style instead: `headerFunction(HTTP_HDR_ABC, m -> m.getHeaders().get(HTTP_HDR_ABC).toString(), true)`